# ASP.NET MVC4 logged in but still needs to login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to ASP.NET and I'm facing a strange problem.

I'm succefully logged in (my login partial view is showing my username using `User.Identity.Name` when `Request.isAuthenticated` is true), nevertheless, when I try to access a Controller that is protected by `[Authorize(Roles="Teacher")]` (I'm logged as a teacher), he is pretty much always redirecting me to the login page. So I login and I can access the webpage, but if I refresh something like 30 seconds after I still have to login knowing that my username is still printed and I still seem to be logged.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using IIS 7.5, IIS 8, IIS express or the VS.NET Dev Server? Does this happens when you debug the app or in release mode?

Comment: Hey, IIS Express in Debug mode!

Comment: Ok it definately seems to be a Roles problem. I made the following stuff : in HomeController, if Request.isAuthenticated is true, redirect to another controller. In this other controller, if user is not in a given role (which I am in), redirect to Index. This ended in an infinite loop and Chrome crashed. So it looks like .NET doesn't manage to load Roles or something... Do someone have already seen that?

Comment: Can you post your web.config roleManager section

Comment: <roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true"></roleManager> No special cookie is added by the way, I just only have the .ASPXAUTH or so cookie

Comment: Not a direct solution, but add Glimpse to your project.  might give you more information

Answer (score 2):

Check which roles the authenticated user has after successfully logging in. Add the following line into an Action method within your HomeController. For example:

```
public void CheckRoles()
{
    foreach (var role in Roles.GetRolesForUser())
    {
        Response.Write(role + "<br/>");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Authorize filter you are using looks correct. Have you checked the spelling of the role? Maybe the role is "Teachers" instead of "Teacher" or something like that. To be safe, make sure the case of the role name is the same.

Comment: Roles name are exact since when I want to access a protected controller for a specific role, I can access it but I have to enter my credentials again in the login form, knowing that I'm already logged in!

Answer (score 0):

A good start is to figure out what kind of Prinicipal your user is.

In your controller, put the following and a break point on the line.

```
var user = User;
```

User will give you the current principal and look at it in the debugger. When I run into situations like this, it is because I might have Forms Authentication enabled and windows roles manager on.

Seeing what the Principal is will quickly help you isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The teacher is Login?
And  the Teacher is Role?
Is for this logined user exists apropriate record in webpages_UsersInRoles table?